# How can viewport shading functionality be used to preview render result in Blender 2.80?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I could make a glass cube in Blender 2.79b in Cycles Render. Also, I could use the Viewport Shading feature in Blender 2.79b to see my desired result.

But in Blender 2.8, it didn't seem to do anything like that. When I tried the same process in creating a simple glass cube in 2.8, it didn't seem to have the desired result. I mean, I tried using 2.8's Viewport Shading part and set it to Cycles in 2.8, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

2.8 is a little new to me. Does anyone understand my situation here? If so, how did you guys overcome this?

I just feel like 2.8 is not well-developed yet and that I should probably use 2.79b at this moment for now.

[image]

Comment: "*I just feel like 2.8 is not well-developed yet and that I should probably use 2.79b at this moment for now.*" Bingo!

Comment: That's odd. If I set to Cycles and set the cube to glass, I certainly get a glassy material. Yours looks like it is rendered in Eevee. Are you sure you are in Cycles?

Comment: @edna Sure, I tried it in Cycles, but it doesn't seem to do it as well. Do you have any proof of how you could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Switch to *Cycles*, Add a [glass shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/glass.html), press <kbd>Z</kbd> and set the viewport to *rendered*:

[image: Cube Cycles]